# Short story - Boy acquires a pendant or earring that causes trash to be attracted to him

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a short story anthology book almost 10 years ago written by one author,  I think.  The only short story I can recall is about a boy who finds either a pendant or an earring that magically makes trash all around him get attached to his body. He tries to get away from piles of trash since he can't figure out what the hell is causing it. He also gets into a taxi while he and the driver see all the piles of trash chasing them.  Under to know who wrote this story and what the name of the book is,  please.

Comment: Can you recall anything else about the anthology that might give a clue as to the author’s identity?

Answer (score 2):

**"[Sloppy Jalopy](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1031203)"** (1991) from *[Unmentionable!](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/953413.Unmentionable_)*, by Aussie author Paul Jennings

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unmentionable!#Sloppy_Jalopy):

> When a boy gets his earrings confiscated at school, he buys a new one. But this one is enchanted; it causes whoever wears it to get rubbish attracted to them. Was later adapted as an episode of *Round The Twist*.